# Why is rsp zero in a 64bit application?

Tags: gdb, x86-64

I'm attaching to a running 64bit process using gdb, when I check info registers, rsp is always 0x0.

In 32 bits, esp had a value I could save and restore (when switching between cooperative, non-pthread threads). In 64 bit, for whatever reason the stack pointer is zero.

Comment: GDB bug, perhaps? Are you certain the stack pointer is actually zero?

Comment: (gdb) info registers rax 0xfffffffffffffffc -4 rbx 0x7fff7aa452dc 140735250977500 rcx 0xffffffffffffffff -1 rdx 0x0 0 rsi 0x0 0 rdi 0x7fff7aa45200 140735250977280 rbp 0x7fff7aa45200 0x7fff7aa45200 **rsp 0x0 0x0** r8 0xfffffffffffffffc -4 r9 0x80 128 r10 0x8 8

Comment: Well, does your *program* think `$rsp` is zero?

Comment: I don't think the program would work without a stack pointer.

Comment: In other words, GDB might be wrong?

Comment: Also, specify the version of GDB and the OS you are using. With `gdb 6.3.50-20050815` on Mac OS X (10.7), I get a non-zero `rsp`.

Comment: GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5)